# Functions that are not replication safe

Tags: mysql, replication, string-length

One of my colleague says Length() function in mysql is not replication safe. This function is used in update statement. Is this true? What else should we take in to consideration when writing a query and taking replication into account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the table you are replicating too could have a different character set. There is no requirement for tables between master and slave to be exactly the same, have the same indexes etc.

```
mysql> create table replic(
field1 varchar(20) character set latin1,
field2 varchar(20) character set utf16,
field3 varchar(20) character set utf32);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into replic values('Adrian', 'Adrian', 'Adrian');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> select length(field1), length(field2), length(field3) from replic;
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| length(field1) | length(field2) | length(field3) |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|              6 |             12 |             24 |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: well to be honest, I am still learning replication. BTW I was expecting to win my argument, and I think you ruined it for me :). But let me get back to you after cross checking something. Because I believe that table in both master and slave are exactly similar to each other. But I totally get what you explained here. Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome, I am still learning too after 20 years in the industry. Sorry about the argument ;-)

Comment: ok .now I have to investigate the query and try to remove length function in the where  clause of query, need to come up according to DB Design. Thank you agin.